# CodeIgniter - query binding "IN" parameter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a following query in my CodeIgniter, which I'm trying to bind via parameter.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN (?)"
$ids = "1,2,3,4";
$this->db->query($q, array($ids));
```

Above is not working, because the query binding treats $ids as string. How can I parameterize my query, but still be able to do "IN" operation?

EDIT

sorry, I have to use "raw SQL query". Above query is just a part of a much larger + complex query, which I can't use ActiveRecord for. Also I'm using Postgres.

Comment: Maybe [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) ? Just a workaround, if no suitable answers supplied.

Comment: @ericbae I have updated my answer check that.

Comment: @ericbae are u enclosing $ids with single quotes??? in the query?

Comment: `$this->db->query($q, explode(",",$ids));`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of string put it in array

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN (?)"
$ids =  array(1,2,3,4);
$this->db->query($q, $ids);
```

You can achieve same thing like this without binding

Alternative

```
$ids =  array(1,2,3,4);
$this->db->where_in('id',$ids);
$this->db->get('my_table');
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on this - it's interpreting it as string "Array" - error on "id IN (Array)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$ids = "('1','2','3','4')";
$q = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN ".$ids;
$this->db->query($q);
```

<strike>you should use the</strike>

```
$ids = array('1','2','3','4');
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
```

The [where_in](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#where_in) is used in codignitor.

Comment: I don't think that will sanitize the parameter $ids and prevent it from SQL injection.

Comment: @ericbae If you are affair ed with sql injection then why are using the query to execute and there is used PDO in codignitor so be cool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with [where_in](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_Table');
$this->db->where_in('id',$ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->query($q, explode(',', $ids));
```

or

```
$this->db->where_in('id', explode(',', $ids))->get('my_table');
```

Active Records documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 0):

Use FIND_IN_SET like this

```
select * from table where FIND_IN_SET('$ids', id);
```

Answer (score 0):

point is

```
$ids = "1,2,3,4";
$a = array($ids);
//$a[0] = "1,2,3,4";

//not  $a[0]=1;$a[1]=2;$a[2]=3;$a[3]=4;
```

want to keep your style

```
 $ids = "1,2,3,4";
$a = explode(",",$ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN ?"
$ids = "1,2,3,4";
$this->db->query($q, explode(",", $ids));
```