# How can I use IN-operator for bound queries in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, in-operator

"I am adapting some of my queries to prevent SQL injection by rewriting them with bound parameters. This is straightforward enough for simple queries:

e.g.

```
// Old code 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = 4 AND author = 'Bob'";
$this->db->query($sql);

// New Bound SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND author = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(4, 'Bob'));
```

I am having trouble getting this to work for queries using the IN operator. As suggested [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html) I have tried the following:

```
// Old code 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = 7 AND author IN ('Bob','Geoff)";
$this->db->query($sql);

// New Bound SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND author IN ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(7, array('Bob','Geoff')));
```

However this query fails with the error message:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Array' at line 6"

It seems the query is getting changed to:

```
"SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = '5' AND author IN Array"
```

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**where_in**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data) as

```
$array = array('Bob', 'Geoff');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('id', 7);
$this->db->where_in('author', $array);//WHERE author IN ('Bob', 'Geoff')
$this->db->get('some_table');
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work. I'd rather keep the same format as the normal non-IN queries if possible. Not sure why [the example from codeigniter's own site](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html) doesn't work.

Comment: Try With `$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE author IN ? AND  id =?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(array('Bob','Geoff'),7));`

Comment: Same error I'm afraid. Also the same error if I remove `id='5'` bit altogether

Comment: Which version of CI you use?? May be `binding IN` feature avilable in CI 3

Comment: It means `where_in` is the best answer for IN clause in CI V.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you lost () in statement so try use IN (?).

I think answer is in this question:

[CodeIgniter - query binding "IN" parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436809/codeigniter-query-binding-in-parameter?rq=1)

Comment: The brackets don't seem to make any difference. Same error if I include them.

Comment: So try examples from link